# Смена значения атрибута value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть такая проблема:
Допустим есть такой input:

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'name' value = 'имя...' onFocus = "if(this.value == 'имя...') {this.value = ''}" onBlur = "if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'имя...'}" />
```

Но то, что прописано в самом тэге (onFocus и onBlur) не дает возможности изменять значение атрибута value этого тэга сторонними скриптами. Как избежать этой проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Само событие срабатывает? или что значит " не дает возможности изменять " ?

Answer (score 1):

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdcoo3fo/)

```
 <input type='text' id="name" name='name' value='имя...' 
    onclick="this.focus()" onfocus=" if ($('#name').val() == 'имя...') { $('#name').val(''); }" 
    onblur=" if ($('#name').val() == '') {  $('#name').val('имя...');}" />
```

Comment: Если кому интересно, то менять значение надо было просто так:
$(this).val('value');

Answer (score 0):

Вместо этого скрипта лучше использовать атрибут `placeholder`:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя...">
```

Comment: Идея с placeholder, конечно, хорошая, но может есть другие варианты?

Comment: Так, сейчас поподробней объясню в чем тут дело) В общем у input`a при фокусе значение value "пропадает", а при потере фокуса "появляется". Но это все происходит в html файле. А есть скрипт отдельный, подключаемый, где я делаю следующее:
$('input').blur(function() {
     $(this).attr('value', 'new value');
});
Но значение остается тем же ("имя...").

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в строке:

```
 onFocus = "if(this.value == 'имя...') {this.value = ''}"
```

вместо `{this.value = ''}` использовать `$('name').val('new val')`

Comment: И внезапно в код на JavaScript врывается JQuery :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, там тег jquery имеется у вопроса ))

Comment: Сначала не было, по-моему.